# How do I put a paragraph in a box that is some percentage of the width of the page I'm putting it in?

Tags: margins, boxes, minipage

I have a document that should contain a bordered box with a paragraph of explanatory text.  The box's width should be a percentage of that of the page's body.

I don't want to make the box a fixed width, because I will be making the document in two page sizes.  I hope I'll *only* need to change the documentclass property, and to that end I hope it's possible to make the box width proportional to the page (or body) so that its width will make sense at both sizes.

I tried using `\framebox` but I don't seem to be understanding it properly -- I can't get the text in the framebox to wrap.

I suppose I could make a one-celled table, but it seems like I'm missing a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a minipage with the width as a proportion of `textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

The `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}` puts a block of text in its own block. The `0.9\textwidth` provides the sizing parameter.

To enclose everything in a frame you can use `\fbox`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!  I'm afraid, though, that I don't understand *why* it works... I thought fbox was only for shorter pieces of text, all on the same line?

Comment: @HedgeMage I added a bit more notes. `\fbox` can take more than a line of text. Try adding two minipages without a line between them and at `0.47/textwidth`. TeX grows on you it will take a bit of time and then everything clicks together.

Comment: Yes, fbox takes text all on a same line. By putting text in a minipage you've in effect turned that paragraph into one big character. (Internally, TeX thinks characters are boxes, so that makes sense.)